# Pass model and a string using ajax to Spring MVC

Tags: java, html, ajax, spring, jsp

Hi I need to pass the full model and one string from html to Spring controller using AJAX. I use the below code snippet but it doesn't work.

```
var str = $("#resourceManagement").serialize();
        var agreementId = ${agreementId};
        var tempCnltName=$modal.find("input[data-type='cnltName']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: {str, tempCnltName}, 
            url: "${AGREEMENT_BASE_URL}/checkDuplicateConsultantOnline",
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                message =  data.errorMsg;
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
```

The problem is that if I pass model alone (str) or string alone (tempCnltName)  I can get it in controller but I cannot get both together.

My controller is as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/app/agreement/checkDuplicateConsultantOnline", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody AjaxResponse checkDuplicateConsultantOnline(
        @ModelAttribute("consultantBidModel") ConsultantBidModel model,
        @RequestParam(value = "tempCnltName", required = false) String cnltName,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {

    final Set<String> allCnltNames = new HashSet<>();
    String errMessage = "";
    if (model.getLeadingCnltName() != null) {
        allCnltNames.add(model.getLeadingCnltName().toLowerCase());
    }
    if (model.getJointVentureConsultants() != null) {
        for (ConsultantBidListItem entry : model.getJointVentureConsultants()) {
            if (!allCnltNames.add(entry.getCnltName().toLowerCase())) {
                errMessage = "Each consultant can only appear once.";
            }
        }
    }
    if (model.getSubConsultants() != null) {
        for (ConsultantBidListItem entry : model.getSubConsultants()) {
            if (!allCnltNames.add(entry.getCnltName().toLowerCase())) {
                errMessage = "Each consultant can only appear once.";
            }
        }
    }
    AjaxResponse response = new AjaxResponse();
    if (errMessage != null) {
        response.setSuccess(true);
        response.setResponseObject(errMessage);
        response.setErrorMsg(errMessage);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing the above, add the string to model:

```
var strVal = "consulName=" + tempCnltName + "&";strVal = strVal + $("#resourceManagement").serialize();
```

The model can then have a new parameter consulName and we can get the value in Controller.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, you're already prepared to receive both the model (with `@ModelAttribute`) and an additional URL parameter (with `@RequestParam`)

On the client, append the URL parameter to the URL. Assuming that `str` is your model and `tempCnltName` is your string to submit to the server:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: str,
    url: "${AGREEMENT_BASE_URL}/checkDuplicateConsultantOnline?tempCnltName=" + tempCnltName,
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var strVal = $("#resourceManagement").serialize();
    var agreementId = ${agreementId};
    var tempCnltNameVal=$modal.find("input[data-type='cnltName']").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {str: strVal, tempCnltName: tempCnltNameVal}, 
        url: "${AGREEMENT_BASE_URL}/checkDuplicateConsultantOnline",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

            message =  data.errorMsg;
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Probably the malformed json is causing trouble

Comment: Thx for help but this doesn't work. I just updated my post to show my controller code. I think strVal  doesn't map to my model.